# Change titles of columns in MDX with T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, mdx, olap-cube

I created simply query with T-SQL processed OLAP cube like below:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([linkedserver], 'SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Revenue] } ON COLUMNS, 
                                          NON EMPTY { ([Basic].[Name].[Name].ALLMEMBERS ) }  ON ROWS 
                                   FROM [SummaryCube]');
```

The result of query is the table. Titles of columns in this table are defaults, ex.:"[Basic].[Names].[Names].[MEMBER_CAPTION]" but I would like to change these titles for ex.: "Names". I cannot change using aliases or I'm using aliases wrong way. Can anyone tell me how can I change name of column?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your `SELECT *`, double quote the names of the returned columns:

```
SELECT "[Basic].[Name].[Name].[MEMBER_CAPTION]" as Names
```

You need to use double quotes as SQL Server recognises square brackets as identifiers.

Comment: No, it's not works. I think the beginning of the expression: "SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([linkedserver]" must stay.

Comment: @kenzolek What was the statement you used and what is the error message you received?

Comment: @kenzolek  User mxix has kindly edited my answer to reflect what your column headings will be based on your given script and not your typed answer.  Try this version instead (Names has been changed to Name) and let us know how you get on.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do some conversions as well:

```
SELECT  
        Names     = CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), "[Basic].[Name].[Name].[MEMBER_CAPTION]"),
        Revenue   = CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,2),CAST("[Measures].[Revenue]" AS FLOAT))
FROM    
OPENQUERY
  (
    [linkedserver], 
    'SELECT 
        NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Revenue] } ON COLUMNS, 
        NON EMPTY { ([Basic].[Name].[Name].ALLMEMBERS ) }  ON ROWS 
    FROM [SummaryCube]'
  );
```

And if you switched to the better olapextensions addin  it would be:

```
DECLARE @Server NVARCHAR(30) = 'SummaryCubeServerName';
DECLARE @Database NVARCHAR(50) = 'SummaryCubeDatabaseName';
DECLARE @MDX NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
SELECT 
    NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Revenue] } ON COLUMNS, 
    NON EMPTY { ([Basic].[Name].[Name].ALLMEMBERS ) }  ON ROWS 
FROM    [SummaryCube];
'

CREATE TABLE #Results(
   Names   VARCHAR(250),
   Revenue FLOAT
);

INSERT INTO #Results
EXEC ExecuteOLAP @Server, @Database, @MDX;

SELECT 
    Names, 
    Revenue = ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(28,8),Revenue),0.0),
FROM #Results;
```